# RMysQL Error On linux based machine

Tags: r, centos7, rmysql

I have a database table- db.tbl. I have isntalled R on CentOS 7.0 version.
I have installed the following packages

```
 dbname='db'
 table='table'
 username='username'
  password='userpass'
  hostname='1.1.1.111'
  port=0000
```

I have written the following code to connect with mysql

```
require(rmysql)
conn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), username, userpass, hostname1, port=0000)
```

I am getting this error

```
Error in MySQL() : could not find function "MySQL"
```

I have tried:

```
 conn<-dbConnect("MySQL", username, userpass, hostname1, port=0000)

 Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
 unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbConnect’ for signature 
 ‘"character"
```

Comment: you have to respect the casing of the package name. i.e. use `library(RMySQL)` and not `require(rmysql)`

Comment: I have done that. the error Persists

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the data base name

```
library(RMySQL)

conn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='username', 
              password='password', 
              dbname='database_name')
```

Once you are connected you can send queries to Mysql like:

```
dbWriteTable(conn, name='mtcars', value=mtcars.df, overwrite = T)
```

If doesn't work try re-installing the RMySQL package.
Hope it helped :)

Comment: yes. I have done it. But seems the same error turns up

Comment: Is your Mysql server turned on? Have you tried doing some simple example queries to try that Mysql works?